# making the switch case in switch case statements a port in systemc

Tags: systemc

I am trying to use a switch case statement in systemc and I want the case to be a port of data type int. The code I have created is as follows:

```
#ifndef TRAFFIC_H_
#define TRAFFIC_H_
#include<systemc.h>

SC_MODULE(traffic){
sc_in<int>next; //R,G,A;
sc_out<bool>t_R1,t_G1,t_A1;
sc_out<bool>t_R2,t_G2,t_A2;
sc_out<bool>t_R3,t_G3,t_A3;
sc_out<bool>t_R4,t_G4,t_A4;


void traffic_light();

    SC_CTOR(traffic){
        SC_THREAD(traffic_light);
        sensitive<<next;

    }
};
void traffic :: traffic_light(){

    switch(next){

    case  next == 1:

        t_R1 == 0; t_G1 == 1; t_A1 == 0;
        t_R2 == 1; t_G2 == 0; t_A2 == 0;
        t_R3 == 1; t_G3 == 0; t_A3 == 0;
        t_R4 == 1; t_G4 == 0; t_A4 == 0;
        wait(5, SC_NS);
        t_R2==1;t_G2==0;t_A2 == 1;
        break;


    }
}



#endif /* TRAFFIC_H_ */
```

the error is on the line;

```
case  next == 1:
```

The error message I get is:

> call to non-constexpr function ‘sc_core::sc_in::operator const data_type&() const          [with T = int; sc_core::sc_in::data_type = int]

How do I declare the case so that it will be a port and with which data type because I want to have four cases 1 to 4 so that it goes four times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
switch(next) {
case 1:
    // your code goes here
    break;
case 2:
    // your code for next==2 goes here
    break;
// etc.
}
```

Also, unless you have a `while` or `for` loop in `traffic::traffic_light()`, you want to use `SC_METHOD`, not `SC_THREAD`:

```
SC_METHOD(traffic_light)
```